# how to access api of nested array in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, arrays, api

{
[
"quicktype_id": 1,
"quicktype": "Laptops",
"qucik_details": [
{
"type_name": "car",
"type_img": "car_img"
},
{
"type_name": "van",
"type_img": "van_img"
},
{
"type_name": "bus",
"type_img": "bus_img"
}
]
}

my program:

```
        return listData.map((item,index) => {
            return(
                <div className="itemm" key={index}>
                      <div>
                          <img src={item.display_img} class="Image" alt={item.quicktype}/>
                          <h1 >
                          {item.quicktype}
                          </h1>
                          <div >
                            <div >
                                { item?.quick_details.map((c, i) => <div key={i}>
                                     <h3>{c.type_name}</h3>
                                     <h3>{c.type_name}</h3>
                                      </div>)}
```

In the program, I need to access type_name and type_img.
I tried

```
                   { item?.quick_details.map((c, i) => <div key={i}>
                                     <h3>{c.type_name}</h3>
                                     <h3>{c.type_name}</h3>
```

but not working. I need to access the nested array.

Comment: What is the exact issue? Are you able to access `item.quicktype`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your initial object is correct?

```
{ [ "quicktype_id": 1, "quicktype": "Laptops", "qucik_details": [ { "type_name": "car", "type_img": "car_img" }, { "type_name": "van", "type_img": "van_img" }, { "type_name": "bus", "type_img": "bus_img" } ] }
```

You add a `[` at the beginning after `{` never close it, so I will guess your object should be actually actually:

```js
const listData = [
  {
    quicktype_id: 1,
    quicktype: "Laptops",
    quick_details: [
      { type_name: "car", type_img: "car_img" },
      { type_name: "van", type_img: "van_img" },
      { type_name: "bus", type_img: "bus_img" },
    ],
  },
];
// this is basically what you did, so it should work
listData.map((item) => {
  item.quick_details.map((c) => {
    console.log(c.type_name); // car, van, bus
  });
});
```

Check your object if you receive it correctly, because both mapping operations seem correct.

Comment: <h3>{c.type_name}</h3>....i tried its not working in nested array

Comment: Can you post more about your code so we can try it? As I said, on my try it worked, but the code is not 1 to 1 with yours. Maybe add a minimal example so we can test it.

Comment: Some parts of your API have quick_details as an array, others as an object. Check for example the quick_details of the object before the last one (quicktype_id: 3), it has quick_details as an object and not as an array. quick_details should always be an array, even if it only has one object. Also is not even named as quick_details but its named qucik_details, which could also cause the issue.